# File Uploading to S3, but times out and file currupt

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Bellow is the code that I am using to upload a file to S3 using NodeJS and aws-sdk.  Everything seems to work fine, however the browser just hangs. Also when I try to open the image on S3, it shows up broken.

```
module.exports = function(app) {


    app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        var accessKeyId =  process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
        var secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY;

        //pull var from heroku else send to dev
        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
        });

        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var file = req.files.filechooser;
        if (file) {

            var params = {
                Bucket: 'mybucket',
                Body: new Buffer(file, 'binary'),
                ACL:'public-read',
                ContentType: file.type,
                Key: "ugc/" + file.name,
                ContentLength: file.size
            };
            s3.putObject(params, function(err, data){
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
                }
            }).
                on('httpUploadProgress', function(chunk) {
                    console.log("Uploaded", chunk.loaded, "of", chunk.total, "bytes");
                }).
                on('httpDone', function() {
                    console.log("done");
                });

            console.log("called");
        } else {
            console.log('Nothing to upload.');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete the call to putObject, after rehistering for listeners, to actually start the upload with send.  By default, if callback is provided to an S3 method returning a Response, then you must initiate the request manually with send();

```
            on('httpUploadProgress', function(chunk) {
                console.log("Uploaded", chunk.loaded, "of", chunk.total, "bytes");
            }).
            on('httpDone', function() {
                console.log("done");
            }).
            send(); // Actually initiate the request
```

See

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#send-property

For details.